# Download XML document

Tags: xml, excel, excel-2007

How do I download a XML document from a web server and read it using Excel?

I don't need a full example, just pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try [Connect to (Import) external data](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/connect-to-import-external-data-HP010089898.aspx)?